# How to show and hide textbox in gridview on link button click

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have gridview,which has approve and reject button.When click on reject button i need to show textbox for comments else no.after enetering comments i have save it in data base.How to do this can any one help me

here is my code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  BackColor="White"
                  BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" 
                 GridLines="Horizontal" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                 <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Industrial Zone">

                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblindzone" Text='<%# Eval("indzone") %>'></asp:Label>


                </ItemTemplate>


            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="District">

                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbldstr" Text='<%# Eval("dstr")%>'></asp:Label>


                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Industrial Area">

                <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblnmindar" Text='<%# Eval("nmindar")%>'></asp:Label>


                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Plot Number">

                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblplno" Text='<%# Eval("plno")%>'></asp:Label>


                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve/Reject">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkApproved" runat="server" Text="Approve" OnClick="lnkApproved_Click"><img src="images/approve.png"  style="width:20px;height:20px; margin:5px" title="Approve"/></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" OnClick="lnkReject_Click" OnClientClick="return showandhide(this)"><img src="images/reject.png" style="width:16px;height:16px; margin:5px" title="Reject"/></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkviewdetails" runat="server" Text="View Details" OnClick="lnkviewdetails_Click"><img src="images/viewdetails.png" style="width:20px;height:20px; margin:5px" title="Details" /></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomment" runat="server" style="display:none"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblstatus" Text='<%# Eval("status")%>'></asp:Label>


                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>


</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You want to show a Text Box when a button in ASP.NET GridView is Clicked. Right?

Comment: yes that only reject button is clicked

Comment: Do asp.net use VB.net instead of C#?

Comment: @reporter User choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are doing it with only C# and no Javascript. to view or hide a specific textbox you should trigger a RowCommand Event of GridView:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "viewhide")
  {
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
    TextBox tbComments = ((TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtcomment"));

    tbComments.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

**And this would be your ASPX Codebehind**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" OnClick="lnkReject_Click" CommandName="viewhide" OnClientClick="return showandhide(this)"><img src="images/reject.png" style="width:16px;height:16px; margin:5px" title="Reject"/></asp:LinkButton>
```

**EDIT:** Now You've changed the tag from C# to VB.NET which is not good. because i consumed all my time writing a c# code!

Comment: no i have not changed it.I am working in c# only .In fact your code is helping me bit.